# Restore Files from .WIM Backup File

Tags: windows-backup

A client of mine has an HP 300-1330 All-In-One desktop (Windows 7) which started having blue-screens. HP support had him do some kind of backup using HP Recovery Manager if I understand him correctly. The result is a DVD with (4) .WIM files and two other related files. I think the total is about 1GB of data on this DVD.

His computer is now restored to factory state and appears to be working without any problems. However, we'd like to recovery some personal data files from the .WIM backups. Is this possible? What software do we need to use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Control Panel, Backup and Restore.

Alternatively, [use ImageX](http://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-mount-a-wim-image-with-imagex-in-windows-vista/) to mount the WIM file to the filesystem, then copy files.

Answer (score 1):

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

> (Supported Formats) Unpacking only: ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DEB, DMG, FAT, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, VHD, **WIM**, XAR and Z.

Comment: AFAICS 7-Zip won't correctly create junction points, though, and I can't see how to create the junction-but-no-listing junction points you find under \Users with `mklink`. Is there a way to extract the junction points correctly from a WIM with 7-Zip? Restoring a computer from .WIMs didn't seem to work without it. Thanks!